# How do you test code that is not a model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I have a class defined in a file my Rails project's `lib` dir that will implement a bunch of utility functions as class methods. I'd like to write tests against those methods using Test::Unit and have them run as part of the project's regular testing routine.

I tried sticking a file at the top level of the `test` dir...

```
require 'test_helper'

class UtilsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should 'be true' do
    assert false
  end
end
```

...but that didn't work. The test didn't run.

What is the normal way to test code that is not one of the regular parts of Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put them in your units directory without any complications.

My Library:

```
[ cpm juno ~/apps/feedback ] cat lib/my_library.rb
class MyLib
  def look_at_me
    puts "I DO WEIRD STUFF"
  end
end
```

My Test:

```
[ cpm juno ~/apps/feedback ] cat test/unit/fake_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class FakeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  def test_truth
    require 'my_library'

    puts "RUNNING THIS NOW"
    MyLib.new.look_at_me
    assert true
  end
end
```

And running it:

```
[ cpm juno ~/apps/feedback ] rake test:units
(in /home/cpm/apps/feedback)
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -Ilib:test "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/fake_test.rb"
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
RUNNING THIS NOW
I DO WEIRD STUFF
.
Finished in 0.254404 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
Loaded suite /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.00094 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

As long as it ends in _test.rb it should pick it up.

Answer (score 7):

I just stick them in test/unit.  I'm not sure if that's the "correct" approach, but it seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

this is an example of test\functional\application_helper_test.rb that test the helper functionality

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

require 'application_helper'

class HelperTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    include ApplicationHelper

    def test_clear_search_string
        assert_equal 'Park Ave', clear_search_string('street Park Ave')
    end
end
```